# Can the status bar in Sublime Text 2 show you what Symbol you are in?

Tags: sublimetext2

In Textmate you were able to see what Symbol (aka function) you were in by looking at the status bar: (Outlined in red)

[image]

I know in Sublime Text 2 I can get to a symbol quickly using command + r but is there any way to get something similar to Textmate's status bar showing in ST2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use [this plugin: `function name display`](https://github.com/akrabat/SublimeFunctionNameDisplay), which does exactly that. You can set it to show any combination of file/ class/ function/ arguments. Its nice.